# Why does "Javascript the Good Parts" claim that "A property value can be any Javascript value except for undefined"?

Tags: javascript

As mentioned in the topic JS the Good Parts seems to claim that a property value can't be undefined. However if you do the following in Chrome's console for example:

```
var foo = {}
foo.bar = undefined
foo
```

Then click to expand the foo object you can still see that foo contains a property called bar with the value undefined. Of course from the Javascript side you can't tell the difference between foo.bar returning undefined and foo.unexistingproperty returning undefined. But what is the point of the console still clinging to the property that was set to undefined?

Comment: I think you could call it a fairly useless Chrome 'feature' :)

Comment: @sje397: Not useless at all. There's a difference between a property existing and being undefined and a property not existing. See my answer.

Comment: So like a lot of answers said I know that you can use delete to get rid of the property and so on. But the main idea with my question was why the book claims the value can't be undefined. Clearly this seems to be an incorrect statement by Crockford.

Comment: @Sam: I don't have the book to hand. Could you quote the relevant part from it? I suspect he may simply be recommending against assigning `undefined` to a property, which is not unreasonable advice.

Comment: No the formulation in the topic is an actual quote from the book. It's not worded in the way that most of the recommendations in the book where Crockford first mentions that something can be done, but recommends it. The text is from Chapter 3 Objects and does say that "A property value can be any value except for undefined".

Comment: @Sam: In which case, Crockford's wrong on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`undefined` is Javascript's way of telling you that a value doesn't exist instead of throwing an error when you access the property without a try/catch block. Although technically what Chrome is displaying is wrong by Crockford's account, it is at least logical; the property exists, albeit as `undefined`.

When you want to remove a property, you can use the [`delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/operators/special_operators/delete_operator):

```
delete foo.bar;
```

Comment: You don't get an error when you try to access an undefined property. You only get an error when you try to access an undeclared variable. And if Crockford's book says that then it's Crockford that's wrong, not Chrome.

Comment: I wasn't saying you'd get an error, I'm just saying that Javascript returns `undefined` as an alternative mechanism to just throwing a _Property not found_ error.

Comment: OK. Although JavaScript does throw errors in general, so accessing an undefined property seems to be something that JavaScript expects and doesn't consider an error.

Comment: Well it still throws errors when trying to acccess undeclared variables, but it treats non-existant properties differently (returning `undefined`).

Answer (score 7):

There's a difference between a property existing and being undefined and a property not existing, so Chrome is being sensible here. If you assign a value to a property then the property fundamentally exists in that object. One difference is that a property that has been explicitly set to be undefined will show up in a `for...in` loop:

```
var foo = {};
foo.bar = undefined;

// The following will alert "bar"
for (var i in foo) {
    alert(i);
}
```

Another is that `"bar" in foo` will return `true`, as will `foo.hasOwnProperty("bar")`.

Comment: I suppose a useful addendum might be to mention the usefulness of declaring vars for use in the global scope. Something you cover, but didn't note (e.g. var a; function doSomething(){a=(a)?0:1;return a;}

Answer (score 4):

Technically, undefined is a valid value to assign to a variable. It does make a difference albeit usually not useful:

```
var foo = {
    bar: undefined
};

foo.hasOwnProperty("bar"); // returns true
foo.hasOwnProperty("bat"); // returns false
```

Also:

```
for (var n in foo) {
    console.log(n, foo[n]); // should log "bar" and "undefined"
}
```

I personally would follow the advise given by Crockford in this case. Assigning `undefined` as a value can lead to confusing code and should therefore be considered bad. It surprises people not expecting it.

We already have `null` to use for this purpose which is less confusing to future maintainers. Let `undefined` really mean not defined and use `null` to mean not known.

Remember that when reading Crockford's book you're reading advice on best practices and opinion on how javascript *should* work according to him. How javascript **actually** works is a different matter altogether (and according to him not necessarily good).

Comment: The context in which Crockford makes the statement is not advice or opinion, but a statement of fact.  The complete paragraph is "An object is a container of properties, where a property has a name and a value. A property name can be any string, including the empty string. A property value can be any JavaScript value except for undefined."

Comment: The context of the whole book is Crockford's opinion and advice of how you should think about javascript. Quote from the book itself: "..I chip away the features that are not beautiful..". The whole book is about Crockford's opinion of the facts, not the facts per se. He freely admits that he isn't interested about describing javascript itself but instead he wants to convey the subset of javascript that he thinks the language should have been in the first place. If you want a book that describes or defines javascript then this is not it.

Comment: Yes, Crockford does indeed say in his book's Preface, "..I chip away the features that are not beautiful.." to reveal a subset of JS that is reliable, readable and maintainable.

However, his sentence about no property value can be `undefined` is not true on Chrome and FF, nor does it seem to fall in the category of his opinion.  He reserves opinion for for the book's appendices.  He further writes, "This book will not attempt to fully describe the language.  Instead, it will focus on the good parts with occasional warning to avoid the bad".

I think he just made a mistake in Ch3.